# Swift 4 changing UIScrollView indicator color

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, swift4

I tried to modify the color of the UIScrollView indicators. In my case is a table view.
The problem is, in swift 3 I used the code

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = Color.red
}
```

It's perfect and it work. 
Now the same code in Swift 4 not working. 
I tried with

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let color = UIColor.red
    guard
        let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView,
        verticalIndicator.backgroundColor != color,
        verticalIndicator.image?.renderingMode != .alwaysTemplate
        else { return }
        verticalIndicator.layer.masksToBounds = true
    verticalIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = verticalIndicator.frame.width / 2
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = color
    verticalIndicator.image = verticalIndicator.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    verticalIndicator.tintColor = .clear
}
```

but not working. The scroll indicator exist in my view and is visible with the "Debug View Hierarchy" but is like as background transparent.

Comment: It's unlikely a Swift 3/4 issue. It's probably a change in iOS 11. You are attempting to dig into the private subview structure and that's never a good idea.

Comment: Solved! the problem is...but is not a real problem :D the scroll view is visible only when the elements inside le list is more than the visible view. If you have a short list, is scrollable a little bit, but the scroll view indicator is not visible it will be there only when the elements are more